# Significance Test for a Classification Task

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification, significance

Suppose for a classification task, I have algorithm A and algorithm B, and a labeled dataset of size M. Both algorithm A and algorithm B are ``deterministic" machine learning approaches, that is to say, the algorithms do not have some parameter which is a random seed so that given different random seeds, even with the same dataset, the trained classifiers can be different.

My question is, if I would like to prove algorithm A is statistically better (or worse) than algorithm B, what should I should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the way you described your problem, the only way of checking statistical difference is by varying your datasets. Generate several different datasets, and run algorithms A and B on them, comparing the results (it's unclear if your quality metric is the result correctness or the time taken, but it works both ways).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by varying the datasets? Diving the dataset into several datasets of small size?

Comment: No, I mean generate several different datasets for your problem. If you are only concerned with your particular dataset, you shouldn't go for a statistical approach - just run both, and define a criteria of quality to check the results.

Comment: Assuming for a given dataset, the accuracy of algorithm A is 88% and the accuracy of B is 86.5%, could I claim A is better than B? Is it possible for me to prove the difference 1.5% (88-86.5) is significant so that to make my claim more convincing?

Comment: If you're not using it for a single dataset IRL, no, you couldn't claim. You should generate several different datasets, and run on them all, getting the mean and the standard deviation for each - then you run Duncan's Test on it...

Comment: Since the algorithms are ``deterministic", I don't quite understand how to get the mean and the standard deviation. Could you explain it for me? Moreover, if it is really hard (or impossible) for me generate several different datasets for some particular task, how could I convince people that 88% is better than 86.5%? (it is okay to use other approaches rather than significant test)

Comment: The algorithms are deterministic, but the dataset will be different in every observation. If it's actually impossible to generate several datasets, you can just convince anyone (including yourself) that it's better for this particular dataset you're using. But being better for one case doesn't make the algorithm better.